# Sed problem with word on beginning of line and a multilines search

Tags: sed

I have a text file with the below text on multiple places:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: harbor-exporter
  labels:
    release: mgmt
```

I want to have:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: harbor-exporter
  namespace: test
  labels:
    release: mgmt
```

Because this text is present on multiple places in the file, I do need to search for:
metadata:\n  name:harbor-exporter and append the line **namespace: test**. Next to that, the metadata: should be present at the beginning of the line. What is the best way of achieving this with sed?

I have tried:

```
cat harbor-exporter.yaml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|metadata:\n  name: harbor-exporter|NewString|g'
```

But I do need the word metadata: at the start of a line. So I put a ^ in front of metadata: and that failing.

Command which is failing:

```
cat harbor-exporter.yaml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|^metadata:\n  name: harbor-exporter|NewString|g'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on `GNU sed`, not sure if this requires changes on other implementations: If `metadata:` cannot occur in consecutive lines, the logic can be simplified:

```sh
sed '/^metadata:$/{n; s/^  name: harbor-exporter$/&\n  namespace: test/}'
```

- `/^metadata:$/` if whole line content is `metadata:`

  - `n` fetch next line (pattern space is replace with this new line)
  - `s/^  name: harbor-exporter$/&\n  namespace: test/` add required line if the next line so fetched has the content   `name: harbor-exporter`

Also, you might be better off with a tool that understands YAML such as https://github.com/TomWright/dasel

Comment: Here's an example of how you could do it with dasel.

`$ cat file.yaml  | dasel put -r yaml -t string -v 'test' 'metadata.namespace'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;/metadata:/{n;/name: harbor-export/!ba;p;s/\S.*/namespace: test/}' file
```

Match on a line containing `metadata`, print it and fetch the next line. If that line does not contain `name: harbor-export`, start again. Otherwise, print that line and replace it with `namespace:test`.